# Tilegrid made of RectangleShape in SFML gives conversion error

Tags: c++, type-conversion, sfml, tile

I am learning C++ and want to get into graphics. I am using SFML, and am trying to make a snake game. I want to use rectangle shapes and update the position of each rectangle by referring to an array and factor of 40 (my tilesize). I believe I got the for loops right, but am struggling to use `sf::setPosition`. It gives me a conversion error. Here is my code:

```
#include <SFML\Graphics.hpp>

int main() 
{
    int xWindow = 1280; //Divided by 40 pixels, equals to a width of 32 tiles
    int yWindow = 720; //Divided by 40 pixels, equals to a height of 18 tiles
    float array[32][18] = { 0 };

    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(xWindow, yWindow), "Title"); //32 & 18

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        ////////Grid variables/////////
        int xFactor = 32;
        int yFactor = 18;
        int size = 40;
        ////////Events////////

        ////////draw////////
        window.clear();

        for (int i = 0; i <= 31;i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j <= 17; j++)
            {
                sf::RectangleShape block(sf::Vector2f(size, size));
                block.setFillColor(sf::Color::Blue);
                block.setPosition(array[i * size][j * (size)]); //ERROR OCCURS HERE: cannot convert argument 1 from 'float' to 'const sf::Vector2f &'
                window.draw(block);
            }
        }

        ///////Display//////
        window.display();
    }
}
```

I am thinking that setPosition only takes float or vector as input, but if I'm not mistaken you can't move through an array with anything other than integers?

How would set up a simple grid like this in SFML C++?

Thanks for any answers!

Answer (score 2):

A position is 2 numbers, an x and y cordinate. `array[i * size][j * (size)]` is just one number in your 2d float array.

I would go for something like this instead

```
block.setPosition(i*size, j*size);
```

Comment: Thank you, I have edited my code, so now I have a x-parameter and y-parameter like following: block.setPosition((array[i] * size),(array[j] * size)); I changed my size variable to float. The rest of the code remains the same. When testing I receive an error message telling me: illegal, left operand type  has type 'float[18]'. Any ideas on what could cause this problem? Thanks

Comment: @RasmusH Why do you think you need the array in the first place? The error is due to the fact that you have `float array[32][18]`, so `array[0]` is the first float array of size 18. `array[1]` is the second float array of size 18 etc. `array[0][0]` would be the first float in the first float array of size 18.

Comment: I get the theory of moving through the float, that's why I use 0-17 and 0-31 in my for loops. My idea is that I want to make a snake game where the snake moves through tiles and I figured arrays might be a good way of doing it, thus I also wanted to use rectangleshapes to form the tiles. As the tilegrid is set up properly, my plan is to change the color of a tile to red, if the snakehead is on top that place in the array. I want to check this by using "if" and check towards the arrays values. If 0 -> render backgroundtile, if 1 -> render snakehead etc.